# Having trouble making an indent using the Boolean modifier

Tags: modeling

I am very new to blender, and I was wondering if there was a way to fix this issue that I have been having. For my Gameboy model that I have been trying to make I need to create an indent where the button would extrude from. I found the the Boolean modifier would probably suit this task, but I am not sure how to simplify it or get rid of all of the pinching. Thanks in advance.
 [image: Boolean difference with lots of pinching.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use boolean, but as you want to end up with only quads you should use less vertices so that it will be easier to correct the topology.

Here are 2 tries, one with a circle printed with *Knife Project* tool then correcting the topology with some vertices merge, additional edges, the other using <kbd>W</kbd> > *LoopTools* > *Circle*.

[image]

[image]